# Error during Load data infile: Data truncated for column user_type at row 392. user_type is empty in row 393

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, newline, load-data-infile

```
load data infile "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Table-2 events.csv" 
into table events 
fields terminated by "," 
lines terminated by "\r\n" 
ignore 1 lines 
(user_id, occurred_at, event_type, event_name, location, user_type, device);
```

It repeatedly shows the Data truncated error. Describing table shows that it is allowed to have null values. The datatype is double. At Row 393 onwards the column starts to have null values, which is what is the problem I guess. How do I resolve this?

Initially the column user_type was the last column so I even tried rearranging (thinking its a newline character problem) but that did not resolve it. I even changed the data type to int to see if it would help, and no it didn't

This is how it looks

| Field | Type | Null |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | double | YES |
| occurred_at | text | YES |
| event_type | text | YES |
| event_name | text | YES |
| location | text | YES |
| user_type | double | YES |
| device | text | YES |

This is how the csv file looks at around 392

```
11768,01-05-2014 08:05,engagement,home_page,France,3,macbook pro
11768,01-05-2014 08:05,engagement,like_message,France,3,macbook pro
11769,01-05-2014 02:37,signup_flow,create_user,United Kingdom,,lenovo thinkpad
11770,01-05-2014 06:07,signup_flow,create_user,Japan,,iphone 5s
11770,01-05-2014 06:07,signup_flow,enter_email,Japan,,iphone 5s
11770,01-05-2014 06:08,signup_flow,enter_info,Japan,,iphone 5s
11770,01-05-2014 06:08,signup_flow,complete_signup,Japan,3,iphone 5s
11770,01-05-2014 06:08,engagement,login,Japan,3,iphone 5s
11770,01-05-2014 06:09,engagement,like_message,Japan,3,iphone 5s
```

Comment: Please add table definition as text and some rows from file around where you think error is creeping in.

Comment: Odd choice of datatypes, SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename> is more useful than describe, do you really have empty rows in the file?

Comment: Data wasn't mine, show create table gives CREATE TABLE `events` (
   `user_id` double DEFAULT NULL,
   `occurred_at` text,
   `event_type` text,
   `event_name` text,
   `location` text,
   `user_type` text,
   `device` text
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

Comment: Use *LOAD DATA INFILE '...' **IGNORE** INTO TABLE ...*

Answer (score 0):

Empty values can be handled using input preprocessing see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

for example

```
load data infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\data.txt'
into table t 
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\r\n'
#ignore 1 lines 
(user_id
, occurred_at, event_type, event_name, location, @user_type, device
)
set user_type=case when @user_type = '' then null else @user_type end;
```